# TiKZ drawing / structure like the following one

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing

I need to create the following structure in TiKZ,

[image]

but I don't know what would be the best approach.

Any help/recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what the best approach is but with `positioning`, `fit` and some style definitions it is straightforward to obtain a similar looking graph.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tbox/.style={rectangle,draw,thick,node contents={}},
    box/.style args={#1 x #2}{tbox,minimum width=#1,minimum height=#2},
    node distance=0.2em,>=stealth]
 \begin{scope}[thick,local bounding box=solid]
  \path node (A1) [box=1.8cm x 1.2cm]
   node (A2) [box=3cm x 2cm,right=of A1]
   node (A3) [box=1.4cm x 1.4cm,right=of A2]
   node (A4) [box=1.8cm x 2cm,right=1em of A3]
   node (A5) [box=2.8cm x 0.4cm,below left=1em and 0pt of A2.south east]
   node (A6) [box=2.8cm x 0.4cm,above left=1em and 0pt of A2.north east,draw=none];
  \node (F) [fit=(A1) (A4) (A5) (A6),tbox] ; 
  \path node (A7) [box=5cm x 0.8cm,below=1em of F]
  node (A8) [box=5cm x 0.8cm,above=2em of F]
  node (A9) [box=2cm x 4cm,left=1em of F,yshift=-1em];
  \draw[->] (A9.100) -- ++ (0,1.5em) -| (A1);
  \draw[->] (A5)  -| (A1.-80);
  \draw[->] (A5)  -| (A3);
  \draw[->] ([xshift=-5em,yshift=-0.5em]A8.south west) -- ([xshift=5em,yshift=-0.5em]A8.south east);
  \draw[<-] ([xshift=-5em,yshift=-0.5em]A7.south west) -- ([xshift=5em,yshift=-0.5em]A7.south east);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[dashed,local bounding box=dashed]
  \path ([yshift=-4em]solid.south) coordinate (aux)
   node (B1) [box=3.5cm x 0.8cm,left=2em of aux]
   node (B2) [box=3.5cm x 0.8cm,right=2em of aux];
   \draw[->] (B1)  -| (A9.-100);
   \draw[->] (B1.north-|A1.-100)  -- (A1.-100);
   \draw[->] (A4)  |- (B2);
   \draw (B1) -- (B2);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are able to ask a more abstract question there may well be a more powerful approach.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure I will ask more questions later.